# Help with kanji

Tags: kanji

What is the kanji on this teabox?

I tried various websites that let you look up kanji, but I could not find an exact match.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look like 壽 and 福 to me.

Comment: And, the two kanji have many different ways to write in the old time in China (over 100 years ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one:

https://tangorin.com/words?search=%E5%A3%BD

The second one:

https://tangorin.com/words?search=%E7%A6%8F